# C# Can I use WebSocket to create server and then use ClientWebSocket to create client?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, server, client

Is this the only way to create websocket - Server Using HttpListener and Client With ClientWebSocket?
I want to implement a websocket server and client separately, and build ReceiveAsync function especailly in websocket server side, since I want to send audio buffer from client side to server side constantly. I mainly want to achieve receive function in server side like this:

> result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, stoppingToken)

So is there anyone knowing how to achieve this, any example I can have a look? Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of SignalR?

Comment: Yes, a little bit, any suggestion？

Comment: Given that you seem to be in control of both sides of the development (client and server), my suggestion would be "use SignalR"